# Angular 4 set scoped style dynamically based on CSS string coming from data fetched from the server

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular 4 based website, where user can edit parts of the page content (I'm using Grapes JS editor for this). Upon saving their edits the HTML content and CSS rules are saved to a model on the server (It's a Rails 5 + Angular 4 site).

Now, in order for the content to be displayed just as the user styled it, I need to somehow inject the CSS into the Angular view template, but it also should be scoped, so that the CSS rules don't leak out onto the other, non-editable, parts of the page.

Below is an example of how I was trying to interpolate the CSS string, but this does not seem to actually inject the user CSS into the content displayed by the browser:

```
// User content component view template.
<style>{{ userCss }}</style>
<div class="content" [innerHtml]="userHtml">
</div>

// Component class (ommitting all the Angular boiler code stuff).
export class UserContentComponent {
  userHtml: string;
  userCss: string

  ngOnInit(): {
    // Fetches the userHtml and userCss strings from the server.
  }
}
```

This seems like an example where  would be appropriate, however it looks like scoped styles are actually not supported by any browser (it's possible to emulate the behaviour with Javascript, but I would like to avoid that if possible). Another way I am considering is to have the user Html+CSS loadable within and iframe element.

However, before working my way around this I thought I'd try to ask a question here to find out if anyone had any ideas how to dynamically use raw CSS strings in Angular templates, such that they are scoped to the current angular component only?

Maybe this is not possible in Angular, or maybe I'm missing something obvious and simple?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

You can use the srcdoc attribute of an iframe.
You build an html document, then sanitize it

```
<iframe [srcdoc]="safeHtml"/>

sanitizer: DomSanitizer;
safeHtml: SafeHtml;

document // build it with the DomParser
completeHtml =document.documentElement.outerHTML;
safeHtml = sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(completeHtml );
```